# Code editor app for Android?

Tags: android, html-editor

Is there a free Code Editor app for Android that can read code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript...) and have features like Syntax Highlighting?

I am using [MIUI](http://en.miui.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HTML Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.HTMLEditor):

- free
- syntax highlighting (HTML,CSS,JavaScript)
- support autocompletion and search and replace.

[image]

Con: it requires Adobe Air (free).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WebMaster's HTML](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO):

- free
- Syntax highlighting and code completion for HTML, CSS and JavaScript files.
- Supports undo/redo feature, built-in virtual keys for tags and popular keyphrases.
- Has built-in Help for HTML, JavaScript and CSS.
- Lite version has limited code completion support: you can select only first suggested item.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DroidEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit).

It has free as well as premium version which comes with few additional features...

---

#### Screens of the interface

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>Credits for Screenshots: André Restivo</sup>

---

#### Features of DroidEdit

#### (Free Version)

- Syntax Highlighting for several languages (C, C++, C#, Java, HTML, CSS, Javascript, Python, Ruby, Lua, LaTeX, SQL, ...)
- Several color themes
- Infinite undo & redo
- Search & replace
- Auto & block indentation
- Keep opened files and changes between sessions
- Open files directly from dropbox or a file manager
- Character encoding support
- Keyboard shortcuts (List below)
- Share documents with other services (dropbox, email, ...)
- Preview HTML files in browser
- Bracket matching
- Go to line
- Run Scripts in SL4A directly
- Configurable Shortcuts

#### Extra features - Premium Version

- SFTP/FTP support
- Dropbox support
- Custom themes
- Run external commands through SSH
- Root mode